# Duplicate mounted_uploader Carrierwave

Tags: amazon-s3, mongoid, carrierwave, fog

So I have an model, Photo, I want to duplicate the whole model including the mounted image.

```
old_photo = Photo.find(id)   
new_photo = Photo.new(old_photo.attributes)

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

But how can I duplicate the mounted image and all it's versions? i.e create an exact copy of the photo, not use the same. (since they can be changed later)

This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287905/duplicate-an-image-on-amazon-s3-that-was-uploaded-using-carrierwave-fog-and-rai

He's asking about AWS::S3::S3Object.copy from the aws-s3 gem, can this be used to achieve this? if so, how?

I'm using fog for the connection to S3, can it be done with fog? If so, how?

Update:

```
new_photo = Photo.new(old_photo.attributes)
new_photo.image.download!(old_photo.image_url)
new_photo.store_image!

raise new_photo  
=> <#Photo _id: 4f1ff69566eaa70ed800001d, image: nil>
raise new_photo.image  
=> https://x.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photo/image/4f1ff76566eaa70ed8000020/file.png
```

Any idea why image is nil on new_photo while I still can access it?